# MarkLogic - How to save pdfs to Filesystem

Tags: marklogic

I retrieve a list of pdf files from MarkLogic. I would like to save them to disk.  I tried `xdmp:save()`, but could not get it working.

```
(:from query return:
       /pdf/2179661.pdf
       /pdf/1092813.pdf
:)

let $list := cts:uris((),(),cts:collection-query("/pdf"))
for $pdf in $list
let $file-name := fn:substring-after($pdf,"/pdf/")
   return xdmp:save(concat("/output-pdf/",$file-name),$pdf)
```

Returns this error:

> Error: [1.0-ml] XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) xdmp:save("/output-pdf/2179661.pdf", 
>         "/pdf/2179661.pdf") -- arg2 is not of type node()

Comment: `xdmp:save()` should be the method to use. Can you share the code that you were using and provide any more details to describe "could not get it working" a little better? For instance, were you getting an error, was nothing saved to the directory, etc?

Comment: let $list-pdf := cts:uris((),(),cts:collection-query("/pdf"))
for $pdf in $list-pdf
let $file-name := fn:substring-after($pdf,"/pdf/")
   return xdmp:save(concat("/output-pdf/",$file-name),$pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`xdmp:save()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:save), the second parameter is the `node()` that you want to save.

In the code that you posted, you are passing in the URI of the PDF document, not the actual `document-node()`.

Either use [`fn:doc()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:doc) to obtain the document:

```
let $list-pdf := cts:uris((),(),cts:collection-query("/pdf")) 
for $pdf in $list-pdf 
let $file-name := fn:substring-after($pdf,"/pdf/") 
return xdmp:save(concat("/output-pdf/",$file-name), fn:doc($pdf))
```

Or you could use [`cts:search()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) instead and reference the [`fn:base-uri()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:base-uri) of the document:

```
let $list-pdf := cts:search(/,cts:collection-query("/pdf")) 
for $pdf in $list-pdf 
let $file-name := fn:substring-after($pdf/base-uri(), "/pdf/") 
return xdmp:save(concat("/output-pdf/",$file-name), $pdf)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. so that mean I don't need specify <options xmlns="xdmp:save" <output-encoding>utf-8</output-encoding> </options> inside xdmp:save()